# HASKELL The lambda expression ‘\ xs -> ...’ has one argument, but its type ‘[t]’ has none

Tags: haskell, lambda, types, arguments, type-mismatch

We had to write lambda function in Haskell but it always shows errors. What do I do wrong? all codes have the same kind of error, but I don't understand how to make them right.

```
length' :: [a] -> [a] -> Int 
length' [] = 0
length' (x:xs) (y:ys) = \n -> if length (x:xs) > (y:ys) then 1 else if (x:xs) == (y:ys) then 0 else if (x:xs) < (y:ys) then -1

find :: a -> [a] -> Bool
find p [] = False
find p xs = \p -> if p `elem` xs then True else False

remove y [] = []
remove y (x:xs) = \xs -> if y == x then xs else x: remove y xs 


• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘a -> Bool’
• The lambda expression ‘\ p -> ...’ has one argument,
  but its type ‘Bool’ has none
  In the expression: \ p -> if p `elem` xs then True else False
  In an equation for ‘find’:
      find p xs = \ p -> if p `elem` xs then True else False
```

the errors are the same

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[t]’ with actual type ‘[t] -> [t]’
    • The lambda expression ‘\ xs -> ...’ has one argument,
      but its type ‘[t]’ has none
      In the expression: \ xs -> if y == x then xs else x : remove y xs
      In an equation for ‘remove’:
```

Answer (score 11):

You have a problem with this function:

```
find :: a -> [a] -> Bool
find p [] = False
find p xs = \p -> if p `elem` xs then True else False
```

By its type declaration, it takes a value of the type `a`, a list of values, also all of the type `a`, and returns a `Bool`.

In the `find` case that matches on `p` and `xs`, the compiler must accept the type declaration, so `p` must be of the type `a`, and `xs` must be of the type `[a]`. This means that the return value *must* be `Bool`.

The expression, however, returns a lambda expression. That particular lambda expression has the type `Eq a => a -> Bool`. You can try that in GHCi:

```
Prelude> xs = undefined :: [a]
Prelude> :t \p -> if p `elem` xs then True else False
\p -> if p `elem` xs then True else False :: Eq a => a -> Bool
```

You can fix the problem by *not* returning a function, i.e. not returning a lambda expression.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there are many mistakes: I'll only point out the first ones.

```
length' :: [a] -> [a] -> Int
```

This states that `length'` takes two arguments of type `[a]` and returns an `Int`. This is weird: why a length function takes *two* lists? Let's assume two arguments is indeed what you want and move on.

```
length' [] = 0
```

Here you define `length'` having a single argument `[]`. Why not two?

```
length' (x:xs) (y:ys) = \n -> ...
```

Here you define length having two arguments, `x:xs` and `y:xs`. However, you return a function `\n -> ...` and that does not match with the `Int` return type.

Moreover:

```
length (x:xs) > (y:ys)
```

above you compare an `Int` and a list. Is,say, `5 < [1,2,3]` true? No, it's a meaningless comparison.